# How to get a number from a dynamic class name from a list of classes using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, dynamic

My situation is this:
I have an HTML list element with an unknown amount of classes (has to be dynamic) and I am adding two classes to this list of classes.  Upon clicking a link buried within the , I need to be able to dynamically grab a number from one of the classes I add to it.

My classes I add to the list are 'display-container' and 'display-#' (# representing the number I need).

Below is my current solution but, there has to be a better way to get this number.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`$.each($(this).closest('.display-container').attr('class').split(' '),
         function(i, item) {
            if(this.match('^display-[0-9]+')) {
                currentObj = item.split('-')[1];
            }
        }
    )`

The code I am working on will be going into a plugin (which is why I need the dynamic class list).  An example list element is given below.

```
                    <loop query="itemList">
                    <li class="item-#currentRow#">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vat">
                CONTENT
                                </td>
                                <td class="vat">
                CONTENT
                                </td>
                                <td class="vat">
                CONTENT
                                </td>
                                <td class="vat">
                                    <span><a href="javascript://" class="edit" id="edit-#id#">Edit</a></span>
                                    <span><a href="javascript://" class="delete" id="delete-#ID#">Delete</a></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </li>
                    </loop>
                </ul>`
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the HTML list element?

Comment: Hi, I tidied up your javascript formatting (use the "{ }" symbol). So far as I can see, this is about the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for, but it's much easier if you add the number at the beginning of the class attribute when you are updating the classes and use parseInt to get it out. It means doing `$(this).attr('class', number+' '+$(this).attr('class'))` instead of using addClass() or whatever you are currently doing. Might be a pain for you. But if you do it this way you can easily access the number later on by doing `parseInt($(this).attr('class'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my understanding of your html setup

```
canned my html, using yours.
```

Javascript:

```
var regEx = /display-[\d]+/;
var classesLongString = $(this).closest('li').attr('class');
var yourDisplayNumberClass = regEx.exec(classesLongString );
var currentObj = 0;
if(yourDisplayNumberClass){
   currentObj = yourDisplayNumberClass.split('-')[1];
}
```

you now have display-## in the above variable.

Comment: @jslamka is my html right? is the class="display-container ..... display-98237841" in the ul or in the <a/> ?

Comment: You have it right.  I have to thank you so much to simplifying it for me. I modified the JS you provided for code simplification.

Comment: @jslamka glad i could help, and do i recognize some Coldfusion tags in your html example?  I'm wrestling cfc's and ajax as we speak lol!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var currentObj = /display-([0-9]+)/.exec(
                     $(this).closest('.display-container').attr('class')
                 )[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$('.display-container a').live('click',function(){
    var $cont = $(this).parents('.display-container');
    var rgx = new RegExp( "display\-(\d+)" );
    var cls   = rgx.exec( $cont.attr('class') );
    $cont.toggleClass( cls[0] , cls[0].replace( cls[1],cls[1]+1 ) );
});
```

[not tested]

Answer (score 0):

```
var regEx = /display-[\d]+/;
var currentObj = regEx.exec($(this).closest('.display-container').attr('class'))[0].split('-')[1];
```